# How to get one key and value from a JSON in python?

Tags: python, django

I am getting a data in response when I hit the API URL in django. I want to get content_id from that data to check whether it already exists or not. How to iterate the JSON to find the certain key and and its value?

```
r.json() =   

  {
        "code": 200,
        "status": "OK",
        "data": [
            {
                "cart_id": "36",
                "content": [
                    {
                        "price": "100",
                        "price_id": "1",
                        "code": "USD",
                        "symbol": "$",
                        "name": "Carol of the Bells SATB - arr. Jay Rouse",
                        "content_id": "17408"
                    }
                ],
                "poster_url": "http://devstudio.cnedocent.com/img/No-Image-Vertical.png"
            }
        ],
        "msg": "Contents Found!"
    }
```

i tried `r.json()['data'][0]['content'][0]` but it works in only one data in, if there are more than one data then when i try to iterate content_id with for loop it doesnt work

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @KlausD. i have updated question.

Comment: You are going to show us the code that doesn't work?

Comment: @KlausD. is this a valid json file with the `r.json()` at the top, I'm familiar with navigating json but never seen it with that top line

Comment: @vash_the_stampede The assignment at the top is rubbish. I guess he wants to express that this the result if the given call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General access

```
with open('vash.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

data['data'][0]['content'][0]['content_id'])
```

To iterate over

```
for i in data['data']:
    for j in i['content']:
        print(j['content_id'])
```

Bonus

```
print([j['content_id'] for i in data['data'] for j in i['content']])
```

> ```
> 17408
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this could help. In the code you posted, the first line is a little bit different from what I have seen previously. Maybe json.loads will help you in getting the "content_id" for n number of objects in content.

```
import json

data = json.loads('''{
        "code": 200,
        "status": "OK",
        "data": [
            {
                "cart_id": "36",
                "content": [
                    {
                        "price": "100",
                        "price_id": "1",
                        "code": "USD",
                        "symbol": "$",
                        "name": "Carol of the Bells SATB - arr. Jay Rouse",
                        "content_id": "17408"
                    },
                    {
                        "price": "100",
                        "price_id": "1",
                        "code": "USD",
                        "symbol": "$",
                        "name": "Carol of the Bells SATB - arr. Jay Rouse",
                        "content_id": "999834"
                    }
                ],
                "poster_url": "http://devstudio.cnedocent.com/img/No-Image-Vertical.png"
            },
            {
                "cart_id": "36",
                "content": [
                    {
                        "price": "100",
                        "price_id": "1",
                        "code": "USD",
                        "symbol": "$",
                        "name": "Carol of the Bells SATB - arr. Jay Rouse",
                        "content_id": "34523"
                    },
                    {
                        "price": "100",
                        "price_id": "1",
                        "code": "USD",
                        "symbol": "$",
                        "name": "Carol of the Bells SATB - arr. Jay Rouse",
                        "content_id": "6423412"
                    }
                ],
                "poster_url": "http://devstudio.cnedocent.com/img/No-Image-Vertical.png"
            }
        ],
        "msg": "Contents Found!"
    }''')

for current_data in data["data"]:
    for current_content in current_data["content"]:
        # here I am printing, I imagine you will do something different
        # with the content_id.
        print(current_content["content_id"])
```

Answer (score 0):

With python it's pretty easy to convert json to a dictionary and iterate it that way.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html